# Will first version local database remain in the new version of iphone application

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ios4, version, local-database

I am bit concern about the local database I have used in my application.
I want to maintain the data enter by user in the first version of application in second version also.
So i did one exercise in which I installed app with version 1.0 and enter few entry in my database from app. Then I installed app again with the version 2.0 and the data enter in the first version app are there in the second version also. Does that mean i don't have to do anything in order to keep users first version data in second version app.
Do let me know if any one has any idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the user data (including databases) will stay around after application upgrades.

When you uninstall an application, its data will also be removed.

> Does that mean i don't have to do anything in order to keep users first version data in second version app.

If you have changed the database schema for the new version, you will need to provide ways to continue to be able to read the old data or convert it to the new format. Otherwise, yes, it should just work.

Comment: Thanks for answer... I have not changed database schema. Now will upload new version of app and see what happens... Thanks

Comment: is this like database schema will also update while upgrading app. Like if I have 2 fields in a table and I upgrade my app with a db with 4 field in that table. What will happen in that case?

Comment: @KapilChoubisa: Unless you have some migration support in place, you'll most likely get an error. Try it out in the simulator.